# How to set a variable in outer apply sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I modify my views with outer apply than using scalar function.

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW [bjs].[udv_SIR_SUMMARY_PERFTEST]
AS 
    SELECT  
        dimsite.[SiteCode] ,
        dimsite.[SiteName] ,
        ....
    LEFT JOIN..
    OUTER APPLY
        (  -- convert from udf_BJs_GENERAL
         SELECT  
             LeakCheck = CASE
                            WHEN (SUM(GallonsPumped)/100) + 130 > ABS(SUM(DailyVar))                   
                               THEN 'PASS'
                               ELSE 'FAIL'
                         END
         FROM    
             [bjs].udv_DailySiraData x
         WHERE   
             x.TankSystemId = ts.LegTankSystemId   
             AND Date <= MAX(x.DATE) 
             AND Date >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@ReportDate), 0)) GE
```

In the above outer apply I need to set `@ReportDate` variable. I set that variable in my function as like below.

I just wondering how can I set that within outer apply?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_BJs_GENERAL]
    (@TankSystemId INT,
     @TimeStamp DATETIME2(7))
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @TimePeriod = Date 
    FROM [bjs].udv_DailySiraData  
    WHERE TankSystemId = @TankSystemId  
    ORDER BY Date DESC

    SET @ReportDate = @TimePeriod

    IF (@TimeStamp <= @TimePeriod)
       SET @ReportDate = @TimeStamp
```

**EDIT**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_BJs_GENERAL]
    (
      @TankSystemId int,
      @TimeStamp datetime2(7)
    )
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @leakChk varchar(10);
    DECLARE @allowableVariance float;
    DECLARE @GallonsPumped int;
    DECLARE @DailyOverOrShort float;
    DECLARE @TimePeriod datetime2(7);
    DECLARE @ReportDate datetime2(7)

    SELECT TOP 1 @TimePeriod = Date FROM [bjs].udv_DailySiraData  where TankSystemId=@TankSystemId  ORDER BY Date DESC

    SET @ReportDate=@TimePeriod
    IF( @TimeStamp <= @TimePeriod)
      SET @ReportDate=@TimeStamp 

    SELECT @GallonsPumped  = SUM(GallonsPumped)    FROM [bjs].[udv_DailySiraData] where TankSystemId=@TankSystemId  and Date <=@ReportDate and Date >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@ReportDate), 0)
    SELECT @DailyOverOrShort = SUM(DailyVar)  FROM [bjs].[udv_DailySiraData] where TankSystemId=@TankSystemId and Date <=@ReportDate and Date >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@ReportDate), 0)

    SELECT @allowableVariance= (@GallonsPumped/100) + 130

    SET @leakChk='FAIL'
    IF (@allowableVariance > ABS(@DailyOverOrShort))
         SET @leakChk = 'PASS';

    RETURN @leakChk;
END;



GO
```

Comment: In SQL Server you cannot both set a variable and return a result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make any set operation in outer apply query, but instead of this, you can use subquery like this.

```
CREATE view [bjs].[udv_SIR_SUMMARY_PERFTEST]
AS 
SELECT  dimsite.[SiteCode] ,
    dimsite.[SiteName] ,
....
LEFT JOIN..
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT ReportDate = MAX(Date) FROM [bjs].udv_DailySiraData  where TankSystemId=ts.LegTankSystemId ) TM
OUTER APPLY ( -- convert from udf_BJs_GENERAL

    SELECT LeakCheck = CASE WHEN (((SUM(x.GallonsPumped)/100) + 130) > ABS(SUM(x.DailyVar))) THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END 
    FROM [bjs].[udv_DailySiraData] x
    WHERE x.TankSystemId=ts.LegTankSystemId   
        and x.Date <=TM.ReportDate 
        and x.Date >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(TM.ReportDate), TM.ReportDate ) AS DATE)
)GE
```

Comment: When I do like this I get// An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.// error

Comment: It gives exception because of `and Date <= MAX(x.DATE) ` line. Which table `Date` come from? and why you are making this predicate? if you describe the purpose of the query, I could offer another approach.

Comment: My real problem is, I have 4 scalar functions which reduces my View's performance. So, im trying to use outer apply instead of scalar functions. I got to know, that it will increase the performance of the view. My orginal function I put in my question (edit section)

Comment: Is my approach right? WIll outer apply increase the runtime performance?